# A broken Asus P9X79 motherboard with an i7-3820 processor will be changed for a Ryzen 9 5950X and a compliant motherboard. Will Debian 10 restart?

Tags: debian, boot, cpu

My eight years old computer has a broken *Asus P9X79* motherboard with an *i7-3820* processor on it. Memory slots and USB ports are defectives : sometimes they make it hangs or prevent starting.

I am about to send an order : they will be changed for a *Ryzen 9 5950X* and a compliant motherboard for it.
I said to its seller :

> I'll come with my two current disks, one having Debian 10 on it, and my current video card,
> and you put them in the new computer.

Can I expect that *Debian 10* will boot on the new configuration like a charm, without a change ?
Or does it suffer the same trouble than *Windows* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, if you are using Debian10 x86_64, it will boot up and work.

I might argue that you note the old one is 8 years old. If your debian 10 install was under legacy bios, the new motherboard might have to have legacy bios booting enabled.

I have personally moved Linux from one machine to another with more than 12 years difference and had it come right up. Most linux distros (like Debian) enable practically all loadable modules in the kernel, so it comes right up and finds the hardware.

Comment: Received the new computer. It did, like a charm, and without having to change anything in the BIOS. However, the ethernet wasn't rebuilt correctly on the old O.S. disk.